# Accessing a List Within a List in c++

Tags: c++

i tried to make a list inside a list, now i have troubles trying to access the elements of packets which is in the list of packets which in turn is also contained in a list. (the packet is a class btw)

list> poemContainer; (bigger list)
list packetList; (contained inside the bigger list)

i want to do something like **poemContainer->packetList->elementOfListContained** (access first packet then get the desired data from the packet class)

tried to do what's below but the compiler says that there is no member it2 in list

```
for (list<list<packet>>::iterator it = poemContainer.begin(); it != poemContainer.end(); ++it) {
        for(list<packet>::iterator it2 = packetList.begin(); it2 != packetList.end(); ++it2) {
                if (!(strcmp(it.it2.sourceAddress, packetDetails->sourceAddress))) {// unnecessary loop just
                    it2.push_back(packetDetails); //compare directly to the begin
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    list<packet> newPoemFound;
                    newPoemFound.push_back(packetDetails);
                    poemContainer.push_back(newPoemFound);
                    break;
                }
        }
}
```

compiler message
[image]

thank you!

packet class

```
class packet{
private:
    string sourceAddress;
    string destinationAddress;
    int sequenceNumber = 0;
    string seqNum; //string of sequenceNumber in case needed for the checksum
    string checkSum;
    string lengthOfData;
    string data;
    string padding;
public:
    void parsing(string);
    string addressToDec(string);
    string dataTranslator(string);
};
```

Comment: Can you show us the what the `poemContainer` and `packetList` variables hold?

Comment: Just so you know, there's no need for that inner `for()` loop if you're just going to break on the first iteration every single time.

Comment: Clearly the `it` will not have an `it2` property as they are being separately declared by you as iterators for different lists.

Comment: If you're using `C++1x`, range for-loops should very much simplify this code.

Comment: @MD.TabishMahfuz sorry, i'm just starting up so i'm quite not sure, from what i understood. i'm trying to access in the the first loop what's inside the poemContainer which contains lists of packets, now i'm trying to access the first packet so i could get something from there for comparison. i know it's pointless to get a new loop but i'm not quite sure how to access the list inside the outer list

Comment: Please refrain from posting images of text. They are opaque to too many people.

Comment: @alteredinstance planning on fixing that when i figure how to access the list inside the list since i thought that introducing a new pointer might be the way to get the location of the head for packetList

Comment: So the `poemContainer` should have a list of `packetList`. So shouldn't the inner loop be something like `for(list<packet>::iterator it2 = it->begin(); it2 != it->end(); ++it2) ` and then the if condition would be `if (!(strcmp(it2->sourceAddress, packetDetails->sourceAddress))) `

Answer (score 0):

The first error is on this line

```
it.it2.sourceAddress
```

Basicly the iterator type (`it`) does not have a member named it2.

*Im guessing it should just be*

```
it->sourceAddress
```

Another error is on this line:

```
it2.push_back(packetDetails);
```

In order for this to work you again need to first de-reference the iterator:

*Either*:

```
it2->push_back(packetDetails);
```

*or*

```
(*it2).push_back(packetDetails);
```

Should work

That being said, it is really hard to see what you are trying to do. Also you could simplify alot with range based for loop:

```
for (auto& poem : poemContainer) {
        for(auto& packet : packetList) {
                //bla bla bla
```

Comment: doesn't work for me still,  says that the list<packet> has no member named sourceAddress. like I said, I have a list which is within a list. first is i know i have a list named poem container, i need to access to the list of packets within the poem container and then get to the class members of packets that was within the list of packets. thanks!